# Block domain, website, without waiting for localhost (hosts)

Tags: windows-7, security, website, domain, blocking

There is a related question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/128082/block-website-on-windows-without-host-file).
I can use Administrator, install extra software, whatever needs to be done.

My problem is:

1. I can't block websites entirely. Like in AdBlock Plus, you add a rule like:

   ```
   ||fbcdn.net^
   ||google-analytics.com^
   ||facebook.com^
   ```

   You can't do that with hosts, you need one entry for every sub-domain, etc.
2. This won't block, only redirects to localhost.

   Okay, it does the job, but it waits for the resources, so it takes time to recognize its not there.

Is there a way to do this?

Maybe some kind of app that makes the PC respond there is NO such thing, don't search / try?

Comment: Addition: I have a legal susbcr to Avast IS but I don't use the firewall there. It's yet too primitive. Basically I want to have a blocker stuff. If you know a firewall like that, I'm willing to pay of course!

Comment: (Can't be even called firewall. I don't want to block applications or edit rules.. just block domain, IP, website.)

Comment: Good news, everyone! Avast 6 comes with the old url block. Yet it shows a HUGE picture instead of the blocked resource. Now that's quite.. annoying/useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) can do this, it allows you to customize it the way you want it to be...

Comment: Hmmm I've been using privoxy ..but... if I use a proxy.. won't it disable my pipelining in Firefox for example?

Comment: @Shiki: Privoxy would handle each connection you create as another connection, and would open a new connection to the internet for each connection you make. So I don't think it would disable your pipelining.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your HOSTS entries are taking so long is because you are redirecting them to the localhost, but you (probably) have no web server running on the localhost to answer, so you have to wait for the browser time-out.

Perhaps turn on IIS to answer the localhost requests, or set the HOSTS to redirect them to a fast site like google.com or alike instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect your entries in `etc/hosts` to something like

```
0.0.0.0
```

instead.

Or, you could install [Proxomitron](http://www.proxomitron.info/files/index.html) and add a header filter named:

```
URL: Kill domains
```

Specify the domains you want to kill in the `URL Match:` field to kill them. For example:

```
[^=?&]++microsoft.com/|[^=?&]++facebook.com/
```

And just put

```
\k
```

in the `Replacement text:` field.

Comment: But he doesn't want to do that for each sub domain.

Comment: I understand. But at least the delays will be gone, and no pages are served, from a local web server or anywhere. Hacking `etc/hosts` is a cool trick that many use wrongly, so I think the tip is still useful.

Comment: Well its already better than the 127.0.0.1 method, thanks!