# How can I disable connections to specific domains?

Tags: windows, connection, blocking, hosts-file

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Good free internet filter](https://superuser.com/questions/268630/good-free-internet-filter)
>   [Using wildcards in names in Windows hosts file](https://superuser.com/questions/135595/using-wildcards-in-names-in-windows-hosts-file)

I'd like to block connections to specific domains.

I know about the HOSTS file on Windows, but unfortunately it does not support wildcards. Basically, I'd like to block all connections to *.somedomain.com. The point is that the * can be almost anything so I cannot hardcode all possibilities.

Therefore, how can I block connections to those domains (including *all* subdomains) on Windows?

Comment: @Nifle: Thanks, but if I'm not wrong I'm going to need to install additional software, is that correct?

Comment: You only need to change you'r DNS-server setting in windows if you use [opendns](http://www.opendns.com/) (They have a free option). You might also want to check out windows `Parental Controls` as mentioned in one of the answers in the linked question.

Comment: I think my question is relevant... http://superuser.com/questions/250193/block-domain-website-without-waiting-for-localhost-hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using softwares like [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) will do the trick. Give it a go :)

> Privoxy is a non-caching web proxy with advanced filtering capabilities for enhancing privacy, modifying web page data and HTTP headers, controlling access, and removing ads and other obnoxious Internet junk. Privoxy has a flexible configuration and can be customized to suit individual needs and tastes. It has application for both stand-alone systems and multi-user networks.